# Declare dygraph granularity

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am trying to show a graph with dygraph with a TWO_DAYS granularity but I'm not able to find the way of declaring it.

Any ideas??

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you trying to force the x-axis to show a tick every two days?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [dateWindow](http://www.dygraphs.com/options.html#dateWindow) parameter I think.

> ***dateWindow***
>
> Initially zoom in on a section of the graph. Is of the form [earliest,
>   latest], where earliest/latest are milliseconds since epoch. If the
>   data for the x-axis is numeric, the values in dateWindow must also be
>   numbers.
>
> Type: Array of two Dates or numbers
>
> Default: Full range of the input is shown